# In a REST based system should a request for a sub-resource include the parent

Tags: rest

I'm unsure of REST best practise in the following scenario:

GET /Customer/23 = returns Customer = OK

GET /Customer/23/Orders

In the second request should a Customer AND the Orders be returned, or should just the Orders be returned?

Comment: Only the orders.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the principles in REST is that you have *one* URL to retrieve a particular resource through. For "Customer 23", this URL is `/Customer/23`.

If you start returning the Customer resource also from `/Customer/23/Orders`, you suddenly have two URLs to retrieve that Customer resource, with the associated questions what the difference is between those two Customer resources.

For that reason, `/Customer/23/Orders` should only return the resource that represents a list of orders.